# The adjugate of the adjugate

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For any $n > 2$ and any $(n \times n)$-matrix $A$ over an arbitrary field, the adjugate of the adjugate of $A$ equals $\det(A)^{n - 2} A$.
Is there a unified way, without dividing into two cases – $A$ invertible and $A$ non-invertible – to prove this result ?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92837/proof-mathrmadj-mathrmadja-mathrmdetan-2-cdot-a-for-a/92842#92842.

Comment: are you referring to the second proof (because as far as i can tell, the first proof **is** by dividing into the two cases) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exactly the same *universal* approach in the related problem below works on your similar problem.

---

**Hint** $ $ Denote the adjoint of $\rm\:A\:$ by $\rm\:A^*.\:$ Then

$$\rm\: A A^* = |A|\: I_n \,\Rightarrow\ |A|\, |A^*| = |A|^n \,\Rightarrow\ |A^*| = |A|^{n-1}\qquad$$

where the cancellation of $\rm\:|A|\:$ is done *universally*, i.e. consider matrix extries as *indeterminates*, so the determinant is a nonzero polynomial in a *domain* $\:\!\rm\Bbb Z[a_{\:\!i\:\!j}],\,$ so it  is cancellable. For further discussion of such universal cancellation of  "apparent singularities" see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/98365/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17837/242) and [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/49298/242)