# Turning a recursively defined sequence into an explicit formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, relations

> I have been given the following recursive sequence:
>   $$a_0=0,\quad\text{and}\quad a_k=k+a_k-1\ \text{for each integer $k\ge 1$}$$
>   and I need to give the explicit formula.

I have written out the sequence and can recognize the pattern but can't figure out how to write an explicit formula so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hint: $a_n=a_0+\sum_{k=1}^n a_k-a_{k-1}$

Answer (score 1):

Use generating functions. Define $A(z) = \sum_{k \ge 0} a_k z^k$, shift your recurrence by one, multiply by $z^k$ and sum over $k \ge 0$, recognize sums:

$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{k \ge 0} a_{k + 1} z^k
    &= \sum_{n \ge 0} (k + 1) z^k + \sum_{k \ge 0} a_k z^k \\
  \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z}
    &= \frac{d}{d z} \frac{1}{1 - z} + A(z) \\
    &= \frac{1}{(1 - z)^2} + A(z)
\end{align*}$

Solve for $A(z)$, extract coefficients:

$\begin{align*}
    A(z)
      &= \frac{z}{(1 - z)^3} \\
    a_k
      &= [z^k] A(z) \\
      &= [z^{k - 1}] (1 - z)^{-3} \\
      &= (-1)^{k - 1} \binom{-3}{k - 1} \\
      &= \binom{k - 1 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} \\
      &= \frac{k (k + 1)}{2}
\end{align*}$

Answer (score 0):

Use the method of finite differences. I've worked out this example ([Why does the method of undetermined coefficients always work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2438961/why-does-the-method-of-undetermined-coefficients-always-work)).

You just need to work out the recursive sequence for just the first let's say 5 consecutive numbers. And take the difference from them and  go on untill you have a constant row.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you mean $$a_k=k+a_{k-1}\tag 1$$ Since you have $k$ in the rhs, "admit" that the solution will be a quadratic expression in $k$, say $$a_k=A+B k +C k^2\tag 2$$ Replace in $(1)$, group terms to get $$(B-C)+(2 C-1) k=0\tag 3$$ Since this has to be true for all $k$, then $B-C=0$ and $2C-1=0$ that is to say $B=C=\frac12$. So
$$a_k=A+\frac{1}{2} k (k+1)\tag4$$ and, since $a_0=0$, $A=0$ and $$a_k=\frac{1}{2} k (k+1)\tag5$$

Answer (score 0):

From the theory of linear recurrences, you (should) know that the solution is the combination of a general solution of the homogeneous equation and a particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation.

The first contribution is that of $a_k=a_{k-1}$, obviously an arbitrary constant.

The second is any solution of $a_k-a_{k-1}=k$, where the RHS is a linear polynomial in $k$. By educated guess, a solution could be a quadratic polynomial, let $pk^2+qk+r$.

Then

$$a_k-a_{k-1}=p(2k+1)+q=k$$ and any vaues of $p,q,r$ that satisfy this identity can do.