# Question about the fact : detA⋅I n ⋅adj(adj(A))=(detA) n−1 ⋅A

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to understand how the following fact : detA⋅I n ⋅adj(adj(A))=(detA) n−1 ⋅A

allows us to determine/assert that if A isn't invertible then (adj(adj(A)) = 0.

If A isn't invertible I can't devide by detA.....

Thanks ,
Guy

Comment: What does your question refer to? Do you have a link?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92837/proof-mathrmadj-mathrmadja-mathrmdetan-2-cdot-a-for-a/92842#92842

Comment: I could understand all the proof but I don't understand how it helps to assert that if A isn't invertible then adj(adj(A)) = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already noted: This is not possible but it is not claimed in the link you provided.

Comment: It is claimed in the comments. Do you mean It's not the right way to prove it?

Comment: I might confuse you. I want to proof that if A isn't invertible then adj(adj(A)) is zero. Isn't the link I provided is the right way to do so>?

Comment: No it is not, and as I said no one claims it there. Just read the comments, can't find it.

Comment: It is so weird because the following fact was written by my teacher : If A has rank n-1 then adj(adj(A)) = 0.

Comment: The claim is right, but what you thought of as a proof is not.

Comment: Oh...... Can you please give me a direction to prove it ?

Comment: There is one attempt in the components of the link you provided.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6191/discussion-between-julian-kuelshammer-and-guy)