# Is every invertible matrix $A$ an adjugate matrix of some other matrix $B$? If so, is $B$ unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators

Is it true in general, true for a specific field ($\mathbb R$/$\mathbb C$) or false? could it be that $A=adj(B),A=adj(C)$ but $B\not=C$?

Comment: What do you call adjoint here ?

Comment: Edited. I mean Adjugate matrix.

Comment: The question's body seems to be different from the title's...

Comment: Indeed, the title seems to ask for existence, and the body for unicity.

Comment: I ask both for existence and for unicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental relation is $A\cdot \operatorname{adj}(A) = \operatorname{adj}(A) \cdot A = \det(A)I_n$, so if $A$ is inverible $\operatorname{adj}(A) = \det(A)A^{-1}$.

If you start from some invertible $B$, then you want to solve the equation $B^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(A)}A$. So the solution, if it exists, must me of the form $A = \lambda B^{-1}$. Then $\det(A) = \lambda^n (\det(B))^{-1}$ and the equation becomes $B^{-1} = \lambda^{-n}\det(B)\cdot \lambda B^{-1}$, so
$$\lambda^{n-1} = \det(B).$$

Thus there are as many solutions as there are $(n-1)$th roots of $\det(B)$ is the field : there may be none (if the field if $\mathbb{R}$, $n$ is odd and $\det(B)$ is negative for instance), and there may be several (in $\mathbb{C}$ there are always $n-1$ solutions for instance).

Comment: Did you mean $B^{-1}=\frac{A}{|B|}$?

Comment: No, what I wrote is correct. The equation is $B = \operatorname{adj}(A)$, so $B = \det(A)A^{-1}$, which is equivalent to what is written.

Comment: The equation I seek is $A=adj(B)$

Comment: You realize it's the same if you  just reverse the letters ?

Answer (score 1):

We know that for *any* square $\;n\times n\;$matrix $\;A\;$ we have

$$A\cdot\text{Adj}\,A=|A|I\implies|\text{Adj}\,A|=|\,|A|\cdot A^{-1}|=|A|^{n-1}$$

if $\;A\;$ is invertible . Thus

$$A=\text{Adj}\,B\implies|A|=|\text{Adj}\,B|=|B|^{n-1}$$

Thus, for example, no rational $\;3\times3\;$ matrix $\;A\;$ with $\;|A|=2\;$ can be the adjugate of other *rational matrix*, since then we'd get the contradiction $\;2=|B|^2\;$ , or no *real* matrix of the same order with negative determinant.

Perhaps over an algebraically closed field that can be possible, say over $\;\Bbb C\;$ .

Comment: This only disproves that the claim is not true over $\mathbb R$, but how can I prove that it is true over $\mathbb C$?

Comment: @PanthersFan92 Disclaims over the reals or over any non-algebraically closed field. Over $\;\Bbb C\;$ I can't say, but Captain's answer seems to give a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A\in GL_n(F)$ for an arbitrary field $F$. Using the identity [$\operatorname{adj}(\operatorname{adj}(M)) = (\det(M))^{n-2} M$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/92964), we see that if $A=\operatorname{adj}(B)$, then $\operatorname{adj}(A)=\operatorname{adj}(\operatorname{adj}(B)) = (\det(B))^{n-2} B$. It follows that $B=k\operatorname{adj}(A)$ for some scalar $k$ and
$$
\operatorname{adj}(B)
=\operatorname{adj}(k\operatorname{adj}(A))
=k^{n-1}\operatorname{adj}(\operatorname{adj}(A))
=k^{n-1}(\det(A))^{n-2} A.
$$
Consequently, $B$ exists if and only if the equation $k^{n-1}\det(A)^{n-2}=1$ is solvable over $F$, and $B$ is unique if and only if the solution $k$ is unique.