# Prove that $\mathrm{adj}(\mathrm{adj}(A)) = (\mathrm{det}(A))^{n-2} \cdot A$ for $\det A = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Prove that $\mathrm{adj}(\mathrm{adj}(A)) = (\mathrm{det}(A))^{n-2} \cdot A$

Hello, this question exists [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92837/proof-mathrmadj-mathrmadja-mathrmdetan-2-cdot-a-for-a).

In the topmost answer, when we reach at $$\det A \cdot I_n \cdot \operatorname{adj}(\operatorname{adj}(A))=(\det A)^{n-1}\cdot A.$$

and if $\det A = 0$, what do we do?

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: That would mean both sides are zero.

Comment: @DavidP That's exactly why OP is asking the question, you can't divide by $0$.

Comment: @DavidP That's why I am asking this question. We can't divide by $\det A$ on both sides.

Comment: See the comments below that post, especially by user @N.S. . It is voted 3.

Comment: Evenif |A|=0, for n-2, we have $Adj(Adj A)=A$, For n>2, we get $Adj(Adj A)=0$.

Comment: $3\cdot 0=5\cdot 0$ but we cannot "cancel $0$" to conclude that $3=5$.

Comment: Use the above formula on $A+tI$ for $t$ s.t. it is nonsingular, then take the limit $t\to 0$ on both sides, and use the fact that $\operatorname{adj}$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sides of the identity are matrices whose elements are polynomial in the elements of $A,$ so the result follows by continuity.